# Ubuntu 20.04 - Cannot connect to public wifi networks

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo laptop, and cannot connect to public Wifi networks anymore (I used to be able about 6 months ago). However, I can connect to any network with a password without problem.

When I try to connect to an open Wifi network, Ubuntu tries to connect (I see the Wifi symbol with 3 dots), but connection does not complete. And I obtain the "Activation of network connection failed" popup message.

I read most existing discussions around similar issues but could not find a fix. Restarting the computer, restarting network manager, resetting date and time, altering DNS addresses etc. were not helpful.

Please let me know what other information I could provide to clarify. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe a coincidence, but I just tried to connect to a public WiFi in a train (first time ever with this Lenovo X1 Carbon 8th. gen running Ubuntu 20.04). The login window opened, but stayed blank. `No route to host`. Also tried with Firefox and it could not connect to the login portal.